# Trouble with setting my inputs and outputs ( A complement is direct input(-ed) )

Tags: verilog

This is the `circuit`-> http://prntscr.com/lceyql i want to implement(`structural`) and i am having trouble setting `inputs` and `outputs` due to the `A complement`(`A` and `A complement`).

I am new to verilog.

I also want to run a `test` on the circuit(running it on `ModelSim`) and i dont know how can i achieve all the 0-1 combinations since there is `A` and `A'`(probably will be autoanswered if first question is answered)...meaning something like that:

```
initial
begin
    InA=0; InB=0; InC=0; InD=0; InE=0;
    # 10 InA=0; InB=0; InC=1;
    # 10 InA=0; InB=1; InC=0;
    # 10 InA=0; InB=1; InC=1;
    # 10 InA=1; InB=0; InC=0;
    # 10 InA=1; InB=0; InC=1;
    # 10 InA=1; InB=1; InC=0;
    # 10 InA=1; InB=1; InC=1;
    # 10 $stop;
end
```

The module:

```
module circuit1 (A, B, C, D, E, F);

input A, B, C, D, E;
output F; 
wire w1, w2, w3, w4, w5; 

nand G1 (w1, A, B);
or G2 (w2, C, D); 
nor G3 (w3, E, C);
nor G4 (w4, w1, w2);
nand G5 (w5, w2, w3);
xor G6 (F, w4, w5);


endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in order to achieve what you want you can remove E input and replace nor G3 line with nor G3 (w3, ~A, C); That means you provide the complement of A as input

Comment: Thanks.Didnt knew it was possible to use the ~ in the inputs. And how about the second question . I edited it few mins ago .

Comment: If you want to test all combinations you have to generate stimuli for all input patterns -> you have  4 input bits, that means 2^4 = 16 patterns to test.
you could create 4 bit counter and then incrementally count until all your patterns are generated. You then assign each bit of your counter to one of the inputs

Comment: Ok i got the whole logic. But for the test i am using somthing like that on my post. but thanks though.

Comment: In order to fully verify your design, you need to cover the full state space of your inputs which are A,B,C,D in your case. ~A is not a primary input, its value will depend on the value of A

Comment: In the code you posted you do not generate all the possible input patterns, you can use the following code : 

  reg [3:0] pat;

assign {A,B,C,D} = pat;

initial begin
for(int i=0;i<16;i++) begin
pat = pat+1
#10;
end
$finish
end

Comment: Y ^^^. that was troubling me .And y all the combs i just threw an examble in there just in case . but still thanks.Isnt typing all the combinations not considered efficient?(apparently its not)I mean at least for those circuits. I ll try what your way will post any errors if i get one

Comment: Also i tried the ~A but error pops . says near ~ unexpected ~. Nevermind . I also set ~A in the inputs of the circuit . forget it